# Creating a constructor that accepts an Object or PrimitiveType as a parameter and then creates a corresponding list?

Tags: java, list, object, parameters, constructor

My goal here is as follows:

```java
public ListClass{

    public List fooList;

        public ListClass(Object objType)
        {

            fooList = new List<(((Object)objType).getClass())>();
            fooList.add(objType);
        }

        public ListClass(PrimitiveType primType)
        {
            fooList = new List<(((Object)objType).getClass())>();
            fooList.add(objType);
        }
    }
...
```

so pretty much, I want to be able to pass in an object or a primitive as a parameter, create a List or an ArrayList of whatever type that object is, and then add that object to the List or ArrayList that has just been constructed.

I can't find any information as to how to go about this online; my best efforts were very quickly thwarted, and so I'm asking here (the code above is what I attempted to make work, but could not get to work).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't create a list of primitives in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to be able to pass in an object or a primitive as a parameter, create a List or an ArrayList of whatever type that object is

Generic types are only used at compile time to enforce type safety. Generic types are not available at runtime due to type erasure. You cannot create a generic type at runtime. See [Java generics type erasure: when and what happens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens) for more details.